# Juxtapose plugin issue on boostrap modal, preview is too small

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using this plugin [Juxtapose](https://github.com/NUKnightLab/juxtapose) to preview before & after image.

**HTML**

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="showBigImageModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content align-center">
        <div class="modal-header align-left">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="top: 15px; font-size: 2.5rem;">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4><!-- image file name will appear here --></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="compressed-image"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        var $showBigImageModal = $('div#showBigImageModal').modal({
          show: false,
          backdrop: 'static',
          keyboard: false
        });
        $(document).on('click', 'a.hideBigImageModal', function(){
          $showBigImageModal.modal('hide');
        });

        function beforeAndAfterImage(imgBefore, imgAfter){
          // Juxtapose
          slider = new juxtapose.JXSlider('#compressed-image',
          [
            { src: imgBefore, label: 'BEFORE' },
            { src: imgAfter, label: 'AFTER' }
          ],{
            animate: true,
            showLabels: true,
            showCredits: false,
            startingPosition: "50%",
            makeResponsive: true
          });
        }

        $(document).on('click', 'a.dashboard-image-preview-link', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $('div#showBigImageModal').find('#compressed-image').html('');
          var imgBefore = $(this).attr('data-before-img');
          var imgAfter  = $(this).attr('data-after-img');
          if(imgBefore.length > 0 && imgAfter.length > 0){
            beforeAndAfterImage(imgBefore, imgAfter);
            $('div#showBigImageModal').find('h4').text($(this).attr('data-name'));
            $showBigImageModal.modal('show');
          }else{
            flashNotice('No available large image to preview');
          }
        });

      });
    </script>
```

**Juxtopose CSS & JS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.knightlab.com/libs/juxtapose/latest/css/juxtapose.css">

<script src="https://cdn.knightlab.com/libs/juxtapose/latest/js/juxtapose.min.js"></script>
```

**Here is the actual result rendering in page. (expected result) **
[image]

**Here's the issue putting it on modal. (image preview becomes too small)**
[image]

Setting `height` and `width` works but still some issue.
[image]

I tried to manipulate the css but hard to get the expected result (which preview will fit the modal's height & width)

**How to fix this?**

Comment: Can you add the html, css, and javascript used to render this?

Comment: Could you please add jsfiddle or codepen link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any documentation on the issue, but it seems that if your container does not have a style attribute declaring width and height the plugin will add `style="height: 100px; width: 100px;"`

The only way I found to override it was with the style attribute setting width and height using `px`, or `em` works but gets converted to `px` values, `%` values don't work and default back to `100px`

Try something like this:

```
<div id="compressed-image" style="width:450px; height:450px;"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/mobvLdny/

Comment: Hi @Arleigh you're right, but still having some issue, some image turns not properly overlapped to each other (because of setting static width and height?). please see newly added image in my Q. Thank you.

Comment: You're findings still a big help, will mark it :) Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I worked out the code to tailor it according to your specs. I tried my solution and apparently it solves all the problems you were facing

I commented the code to make it easier to read. I reworked a lot of parts. It is an adaptation between yours and this one from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp). Ah! last but not least, I made the snippet responsive, `makeReponsive` from juxtapose was not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.knightlab.com/libs/juxtapose/latest/css/juxtapose.css">

<style>
body
{
    width:100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* modal (background) */
.modal 
{
    display: none; /* Hidden by default when reloading */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 5%; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* entire modal */
.modal-content 
{  
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 7%;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    max-width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* modal header */
.modal-header 
{
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

/* modal hosting pictures */
.modal-body 
{
    position: relative;
    max-width:100%; 
    max-height: 100%;
}

/* add animation: falling from the sky */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop 
{
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop 
{
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* close button */
.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- trigger opening the modal -->
<a href="#" id="modalTrigger" class="dashboard-image-preview-link" data-before-img="https://www.toureiffel.paris/themes/custom/tour_eiffel/img/tour-eiffel-paris.jpg" data-after-img="https://www.toureiffel.paris/themes/custom/tour_eiffel/img/tour-eiffel-paris.jpg" data-name="Tour Eiffel">Show Comparison</a>

<!-- modal wrapper -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- modal content - the entire modal -->
    <div class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h2>
        <!-- image file name will appear here -->
        </h2>
        
        </div>
        <!-- modal body - image comparison -->
        <div class="modal-body" id="before-after-window">
        <!-- space for image comparison filled by juxtapose.js -->  
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.knightlab.com/libs/juxtapose/latest/js/juxtapose.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
{
    // get the modal
    var $modalWindow = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // get the string that opens the modal
    var $trigger = document.getElementById("modalTrigger");

    // get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var $span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    function beforeAndAfterImage(imgBefore, imgAfter) 
    {
        // juxtapose
        slider = new juxtapose.JXSlider('#before-after-window',
        [
            {
                src: imgBefore,
                label: 'BEFORE'
            },
            {
                src: imgAfter,
                label: 'AFTER'
            }
        ], 
        {
            animate: true,
            showLabels: true,
            showCredits: false,
            startingPosition: "50%",
            makeResponsive: true
        });
    }

    // when the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    $trigger.onclick = function() 
    {
        $modalWindow.style.display = "block";
  
        // select the images and put them next to each other
        var imgBefore = $(this).attr('data-before-img');
        var imgAfter = $(this).attr('data-after-img');

        if (imgBefore.length > 0 && imgAfter.length > 0) 
        {
            beforeAndAfterImage(imgBefore, imgAfter);
            // fill the title
            result = $('div#myModal').find('h2').text($(this).attr('data-name'));
        } 
        else 
        {
            flashNotice('No available large image to preview');
        }
    }

    // when the user clicks on <span> (x) let's close the modal
    $span.onclick = function() 
    {
        $modalWindow.style.display = "none";
    }

    // when the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal let's close it too
    window.onclick = function(event) 
    {
        if (event.target == $modalWindow) 
        {
            $modalWindow.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

});
</script>

<script>        
// defining event listener function
function scaleWindowSize()
{
    
    // resizing the image when changing the window size - juxtapose bug
    var $modalBody = document.getElementById("before-after-window");
    document.getElementById("before-after-window").setAttribute("style","width: 100%; height: 100%");
}
 
// attaching the event listener function to window's resize event
window.addEventListener("resize", scaleWindowSize);

// Calling the function for the first time
scaleWindowSize();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As other guys said the issue is about the width and height of the wrapper.
But adding width and height hard coded and inline is probably not a good solution for responsive design.
Here is an example of how I did it.

I get the image dimensions and set it to the parent div, and this function will be fired on window resize and also on initialization.

```
    setComparisonDimensions( wrapper ) {
        const container = wrapper.querySelector( '.raven-image-comparison-container' );
        //Get images inside the wrapper.
        const images = wrapper.querySelectorAll( 'img' );
        //Images should be full width so we get wrapper width here.
        const width = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().width;

        //Here we compare the heights of the images and then get the bigger one.
        let height = images[ 0 ].height;

        if ( images[ 1 ].height > height ) {
            height = images[ 1 ].height;
        }

        //Now set them to the container of Juxtapose.
        container.style.width = width + 'px';
        container.style.height = height + 'px';
},

setComparisonDimensions( wrapper );

jQuery( window ).on( 'resize', function() {
    setComparisonDimensions( wrapper );
} );
```

Hope it helps.
By the way, I didn't test this code so there may be some errors.